# Quaternion * Vector3 * Distance

Tags: unity-game-engine

Could someone please help me understand the result of the following multiplications?

In the Unity VR samples project, the following two lines are used:

```
Quaternion headRotation = InputTracking.GetLocalRotation(VRNode.Head);

TargetMarker.position = Camera.position + (headRotation * Vector3.forward) * DistanceFromCamera;
```

I can understand the first line - how the user's head rotation is calculated and stored in `headRotation` which is a `Quaternion`.

I can also understand that the `TargetMarker`'s position should be calculated by adding the `Camera`'s position to something. What is this something?

Most importantly, how does the result of `(headRotation * Vector3.forward) * DistanceFromCamera` is a `position`?

Comment: The answer you got is correct. If you want more to explain you can check this answer: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/186252/multiply-quaternion-by-vector.html

Comment: @Jerry Switalski  Thanks Jerry. I will check this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`headRotation * Vector3.forward` return a `Vector3` in the direction forward of your Quaternion `headRotation`. (So the direction you are facing)

As `Vector3.forward` is the vector normalized `(0, 0, 1)` when you multiply it by your `Quaternion` you have a *vector* of length **1** with the same direction of your head.

Then when you multiply it by the distance between your marker and your camera you now have a vector of the same **length and direction** that between your camera and your marker.

Add it to your current camera position and you now have the position of your marker.

Comment: @Joshua Thank you ^^